# Excel spreadsheet VBA code not working all the way

Tags: vba, excel

The code that is running on my excel spreadsheet that I am working on is working fine, expect for when I copy and import information into the protected cells it gives me a type mismatch error and can not figure out how to fix the code.

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C20")) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 Then Application.Undo
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

When you paste a number of values into two or more cells within the C1:C20 range, the **Target** is more than 1 and you cannot use the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) of Target.

Typically, you would use something like the following.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C20")) Is Nothing Then
        'do not do anything until you know you are going to need it
        On Error GoTo Whoa
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim crng As Range

        'in the event of a paste, Target may be multiple cells
        'deal with each changed cell individually
        For Each crng In Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C20"))
            If Len(Trim(crng.Value)) = 0 Then Application.Undo
            'the above undoes all of the changes; not just the indivual cell with a zero
        Next crng
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

However, your desire to use `Application.Undo` presents some unique problems because you do not want to undo **all** of the changes; just the ones that result in zero. Here is a possible solution.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C20")) Is Nothing Then
        'do not do anything until you know you are going to need it
        On Error GoTo Whoa
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim c As Long, crng As Range, vals As Variant, prevals As Variant
        'store the current values
        vals = Range("C1:C20").Value2
        'get the pre-change values back
        Application.Undo
        prevals = Range("C1:C20").Value2

        'in the event of a paste, Target may be multiple cells
        'deal with each changed cell individually
        For c = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            If vals(c, 1) = 0 Then vals(c, 1) = prevals(c, 1)
        Next c
        Range("C1:C20") = vals
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

The new values are stored in a variant array and then the paste is undone. The old values are stored in another variant array. The new values are walked through and if a zero comes up, it is replaced with the old value. Finally, the revised set of new values is pasted back into the C1:C20 range.

Comment: Thanks this really helped but one thing that isn't happening is that in the specified range I need to be able to copy and insert. So if I have C1:C20 and all 20 are filled I need to be able to copy and insert inside the 20 so then I would have 21 and so on.

Comment: That new requirement was not in your question. I suggest you close this question off and start another lest this become a [Russian Doll Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Your sheet must be protected, so you need to unprotect your sheet first:

```
  Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("NameOfYourSheet").Unprotect Password:="YourPassWord" ' Change the name of the sheet which is locked
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C20")) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 Then Application.Undo
    End If

Sheets("NameOfYourSheet").Protect Password:="YourPassWord" 

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```